# stack install ghc-mod fails to construct build plan

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack, ghc-mod

I've been trying to install ghc-mod locally within a Stack project.

However, whenever I try to `stack build ghc-mod`, I get a build plan failure like the following:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for ghc-mod-5.8.0.0:
    cabal-helper must match <0.8 && >=0.7.3.0, but the stack configuration has no specified
                 version  (latest matching version is 0.7.3.0)
    djinn-ghc must match <0.1 && >=0.0.2.2, but the stack configuration has no specified version
              (latest matching version is 0.0.2.3)
    extra must match <1.6 && >=1.4, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest
          matching version is 1.5.3)
    fclabels must match ==2.0.*, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest
             matching version is 2.0.3.3)
    ghc-paths must match <0.2 && >=0.1.0.9, but the stack configuration has no specified version
              (latest matching version is 0.1.0.9)
    ghc-syb-utils must match <0.3 && >=0.2.3, but the stack configuration has no specified
                  version  (latest matching version is 0.2.3.3)
    haskell-src-exts must match <1.20 && >=1.18, but the stack configuration has no specified
                     version  (latest matching version is 1.19.1)
    hlint must match <2.1 && >=2.0.8, but the stack configuration has no specified version
          (latest matching version is 2.0.15)
    monad-control must match >=1 && <1.1, but the stack configuration has no specified version
                  (latest matching version is 1.0.2.3)
    monad-journal must match <0.8 && >=0.4, but the stack configuration has no specified version
                  (latest matching version is 0.7.2)
    mtl needed, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version
        is 2.2.2)
    old-time needed, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching
             version is 1.1.0.3)
    optparse-applicative must match >=0.13.0.0 && <0.14, but the stack configuration has no
                         specified version  (latest matching version is 0.13.2.0)
    pipes must match <4.4 && >=4.1, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest
          matching version is 4.3.9)
    safe must match <0.4 && >=0.3.9, but the stack configuration has no specified version
         (latest matching version is 0.3.17)
    semigroups must match >=0.10.0 && <0.19, but the stack configuration has no specified
               version  (latest matching version is 0.18.5)
    split must match >=0.2.2 && <0.3, but the stack configuration has no specified version
          (latest matching version is 0.2.3.3)
    syb must match <0.8 && >=0.5.1, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest
        matching version is 0.7)
    temporary must match <1.3 && >=1.2.0.3, but the stack configuration has no specified version
              (latest matching version is 1.2.1.1)
    text must match <1.3 && >=1.2.1.3, but the stack configuration has no specified version
         (latest matching version is 1.2.3.0)
    transformers-base must match <0.5 && >=0.4.4, but the stack configuration has no specified
                      version  (latest matching version is 0.4.5.2)
needed since ghc-mod is a build target.
```

If I follow the warning's advice to add the missing dependencies to my stack.yaml's `extra-deps` key, I just get more recursive errors and eventually a build plan that has a build conflict somewhere that's not obvious to me at least and no helpful clues to resolve it.

Here's the stack.yaml:

```
flags: {}
packages:
- .
extra-deps:
- cabal-helper-0.7.3.0
- djinn-ghc-0.0.2.3
- extra-1.5.3
- fclabels-2.0.3.3
- ghc-paths-0.1.0.9
- ghc-syb-utils-0.2.3.3
- hlint-2.0.15
- base-4.7.0.2
- StateVar-1.1.1.1
- deepseq-1.3.0.2
- vector-algorithms-0.7.0.4
- monad-control-1.0.2.3
- monad-journal-0.7.2
- mtl-2.2.2
- old-time-1.1.0.3
- optparse-applicative-0.13.2.0
- pipes-4.3.9
- safe-0.3.17
- semigroups-0.18.5
- split-0.2.3.3
- syb-0.7
- temporary-1.2.1.1
- text-1.2.3.0
- transformers-base-0.4.5.2
- aeson-1.4.0.0
- ansi-terminal-0.8.0.4
- ansi-wl-pprint-0.6.8.2
- async-2.2.1
- base-orphans-0.8
- clock-0.7.2
- cmdargs-0.10.20
- cpphs-1.20.8
- data-default-0.7.1.1
- djinn-lib-0.0.1.3
- either-4.4.1.1
- exceptions-0.10.0
- haskell-src-exts-util-0.2.3
- hscolour-1.24.4
- mmorph-1.1.2
- old-locale-1.0.0.7
- refact-0.3.0.2
- stm-2.4.5.0
- transformers-compat-0.6.2
- uniplate-1.6.12
- unordered-containers-0.2.9.0
- utf8-string-1.0.1.1
- vector-0.12.0.1
- void-0.7.2
- yaml-0.10.0
- cabal-doctest-1.0.6
- comonad-5.0.4
- contravariant-1.5
- distributive-0.6
- haskell-src-exts-1.20.2
- integer-logarithms-1.0.2.1
- mono-traversable-1.0.9.0
- prelude-extras-0.4.0.3
- random-1.1
- time-1.4.2
- unliftio-core-0.1.1.0
- MonadRandom-0.5.1.1
- attoparsec-0.13.2.2
- base-compat-0.10.4
- bifunctors-5.5.3
- colour-2.3.4
- conduit-1.3.0.3
- data-default-class-0.1.2.0
- data-default-instances-containers-0.0.1
- data-default-instances-dlist-0.0.1
- data-default-instances-old-locale-0.0.1
- dlist-0.8.0.4
- free-4.12.4
- hashable-1.2.7.0
- polyparse-1.12
- primitive-0.6.4.0
- profunctors-5.3
- resourcet-1.2.1
- scientific-0.3.6.2
- semigroupoids-5.3.1
- tagged-0.8.6
- th-abstraction-0.2.8.0
- time-locale-compat-0.1.1.4
- uuid-types-1.0.3
resolver: ghc-8.0.2
```

Am I missing something here? Surely this should be easier. I gather ghc-mod isn't supported past GHC 8.2 so I deliberately set up the project with GHC 8.0.2 as verified by running GHCI (not without its own long list of warnings).

I also tried with a 7.x version of GHC and that had the same issues, though with slightly different dependencies.

Comment: Can you include the `stack.yaml` ?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Updated the question with the `stack.yam`

Comment: I don't think you should have anything in `extra-deps` in the `stack.yaml`. That field is only for packages that are not on stackage.

Comment: I agree, but I’m new to this. Stack recommended adding those to extra-deps in response to the initial build failure.